# R Loop - Adding rows without predefined dimensions

Tags: r, loops, matrix

I want to store the results of a test within an R `for` loop inside a matrix or data.frame with (in this case) two columns, *but* an indeterminate number of rows, because the number of rows will depend on an `if` statement.

I am comparing counts for days of the week, and then doing pairwise comparisons. This is the code as it stands now:

```
week <- c(Mon = 401, Tue = 199, Wed = 187, Thur = 202, Fri = 240, Sat = 212, Sun = 244)
names(week) <- NULL
observed <- week


for(i in 1:(length(observed) - 1)){
  for(j in 1:(length(observed))){
    test <- chisq.test(c(observed[i], observed[j]), p = rep(1/2, 2))
    if(test$p.value < 0.002380952) print(c(i,j)) 
  }
}
```

The output is now:

```
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
[1] 1 5
[1] 1 6
[1] 1 7
[1] 2 1
[1] 3 1
[1] 4 1
[1] 5 1
[1] 6 1
```

But depending on the results of the `if` statement in the function, it could have been much longer. Further I want to ultimately erase permutations.

Looking for ways to initiate an empty matrix (or data.frame) in the loop, they seem to incorporate the dimensions ahead of time, such as in `days <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(observed)^2, ncol = 2)`.

I'd like to, instead, have an indeterminate number of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
mat <- combn(1:length(observed),2)
vec <- apply(mat, 2, function(x) chisq.test(observed[x],p=rep(1/2,2))$p.value)
mat[,c(vec < 0.002380952)] 

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1
#[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7
```

Explanation:
 `combn` finds all combinations between numbers and returns them as a matrix (`2` rows by `n` columns). Then we go over the `n` columns and find the p-values. We then subset `mat` for the elements of `vec` that are smaller than your threshold.

Comment: OP wants permutations, not combinations

Comment: Now I'm confused. `Further I want to ultimately erase permutations.` I interpreted this as OP wanting to get rid of permutations and so keep the combinations.

Comment: I think it means that OP does not want to compute the permutations ahead of time and how ahead it is, I have no idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted in terms of the specific issue with this loop, and I find the code nice and clean. You read me just right, please erase the edit if you want.

Comment: However, I was really looking for something more clunky and more universally applicable... the empty matrix with indeterminate rows...

Comment: Isn't it possible to do with matrices or data.frames the equivalent of what you can do with vectors ahead of loops, and start something like `my_drawer_of_temporary_results <- NULL`?

Comment: Ok, so what you want is to create an empty matrix and then every time your if-loop is satisfied you append the pair to the bottom, right? This is horribly inefficient because of the way R works. Read chapter 2 of The R Inferno (http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) to understand why. It is often better to simply create a matrix (or data frame) where you prespecify the number of rows and number of columns, and give all cells the value `NA`. After running all your tests, you can then simply remove all the rows with `NA`.

Comment: Two things before I happily accept, if you don't mind it... 1. `observed[x]` just grabs the column number in `mat` because of the `2` in apply, correct? And 2. I get that the idea is computationally bad, but is it also bad with vectors, like in the `my_drawer_of_temporary_results <- NULL`?

Comment: (1) Correct. `x` simply contains a column of `mat`, which contains 2 values that you use to get the right values from `observed`. (2) You mean, is it bad to create empty vectors and append to them? In general you should avoid it if the vector becomes pretty long. If you only expect < 10 elements in your vector, then it is fine, but if you have no idea and it could be 1 million, then it's better to teach yourself good habits and avoid appending (see The R Inferno). Edit: Since you mentioned somewhere else that you are a beginner, I'd recommend reading all of The R Inferno. It's pretty nice :)

Answer (score 1):

So I created permutations of possible combinations to test, extract each of them using `apply` and sending it to the `chisq.test` and extract the combinations matching your threshold.

```
week <- c(Mon = 401, Tue = 199, Wed = 187, Thur = 202, Fri = 240, Sat = 212, Sun = 244)
mat.comparison <- as.matrix(t(expand.grid(1:length(week), 1:length(week))))
mat.out <- t(mat.comparison[,(apply(mat.comparison, 2,
                                    function(n) {
                                        chisq.test(week[n], p = rep(1/2, 2))[["p.value"]] < 0.002380952}
                                    ))])
```

Comment: not too sure what you mean by removing permutations. if you mean you want combinations instead of permutations, it is an easy switch to the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think there may be a minor problem with the parentheses or brackets, but the idea of `expand.grid` and `apply` row wise makes sense. I really was looking for something more generic, though, something that would not need any type of a priori reference to dimensions (in this case (`length(week)`).

Comment: fixed. I am not sure of why you have that need because at some point you would be supplied a vector to test their values right? At that point, the length can then be taken.

Comment: I tried explaining why I would like the flexibility of an indeterminate number of rows, but I am a beginner at coding. FYI, I'm still getting an error when I run your post. I +1, but you may want to look into it.

Comment: oops this is almost embarrassing. yes another copy and paste error. sorry. fixed now.

Comment: I still do not understand the need for flexibility. because using the solution provided, you can use any length of week and it can vary. if you like you can turn it into a function and flexibily pass it any variable you want to test.